# What is the type of car that Mr. Weasley used to have?

Tags: harry-potter

So Ron Weasley crashed a car in the Chamber of Secrets.

Do we know what type of car it is? If not book canon, what about movie canon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Ford Anglia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles'_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Books/Chamber_of_Secrets/Chapter_5).

> Summer ends quickly, and it is time to return to Hogwarts. After several false starts, everything is loaded into Mr. Weasley's car, the flying Ford Anglia. Mr. Weasley has apparently charmed the car so that everyone fits in easily, though Mrs. Weasley apparently thinks it is normal for Muggle vehicles to be this large inside.

Here's a photo of one:

[image: Ford Anglia]

Answer (score 3):

[image]A [Ford Anglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Anglia#In_popular_culture)(105E), which was manufactured by Ford UK.  It's refered in the books as that make and model.